# I need to find out how I can add a link to a Link list to a file in SharePoint whose filename changes weekly

Tags: links-list

This is a dupe of something asked several years ago and never answered. I have the same situation and need help finding a solution.

The SP site I'm working on has a few files that are updated periodically. I've been asked to find a way to add a link to them in a Links list webpart on the landing page that doesn't require a manual update every time the date in a target filename changes.

The target files all have a fixed location and most of their filenames are fixed. The date portion of the filename changes periodically and irregularly.

We can't add anything from the SharePoint store (heaven forbid we find an easy solution) or use jQuery.

Any leads are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using a search webpart for this.  Add a column to your library called "Show in WebPart" or whatever, then configure the search webpart to display results where that column = yes.  You also get security trimming this way, if that is important to you.  Remember that a search crawl will have to run before the webpart will show updated items, so there will be a delay depending on your crawl schedule.

Comment: As long as the landing page and the library are on the same site.  This can be accomplished with a view as described.

Answer (score 1):

You can add simple workflow to update links. It can be done via SharePoint Designer.

Steps:

1. In links list create column *File ID* or *File GUID* or something like that
2. For each link set ID of file. You can find ID of each file in column named *ID* in document library
3. Create workflow on document library
4. Logic of workflow - Workflow will fired when items changed then will check if links list contains list item with this file ID - update a link.

It will work if all files live in one document library. IF not - additional steps needed(need to create additional column in each document library called *File Guid* and map all links with this column instead of *File ID*)

Comment: Thanks, Raf. That's something I can manage. I hadn't thought of using a workflow.